# function OnClick is not working in JS, dont have any results

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

```js
console.log("conected!");

function click() {
  alert("Your Form has been sent!");
}
```

```html
<div class="body_cont">
  <form class="send-form">
    <h1>Quizz</h1>

    <label for="mode1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="model" class="mode1">

    <label for="mode2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="mode2" class="mode1">

    <label for="mode3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="mode3" class="mode1">

    <label for="mode4">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="mode4" class="mode1">

    <input type="button" onclick="click()" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

I dont have any errors in console, but i dont see alert too:(

only result i have: conected! and thats all

Comment: rename the click() function to anything else and give it a try.
There may be a conflict with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click being fired instead

Comment: Mitch, Thanks Bro, i Love u